# reading cuda data in burst mode

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

I currently have CUDA code that is performing around 3-4x slower than CPU code.

I removed all extraneous CPU/GPU transfers so that most of the computation is being done on the GPU, and only the final result is transferred back to CPU memory.

To speed this up more, I did a bit of reading and figured out that since the GPU memory bus is much slower, accessing GPU device memory is also slow. And, since my computation uses large arrays--and hence many memory accesses--that's slowing things down even when I set `threadsPerBlock` to the max of 1024.

I guess the only option I have now is to copy blocks of data into the MP shared memory operated by each individual block and do my computation on that memory.

I want to know how I can copy a chunk of memory in burst mode into the shared memory most efficiently. Should I do it by copying on the starting thread index in each warp?

Any solutions with relevant code or functions for accomplishing this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are several incorrect statements in the question. GPU bandwidth is often 4-10x CPU bandwidth. GPU load latency can be 10-20x CPU latency. The GPU can have significantly more inflight transaction. The goal of a kernel is to hide the latency of these transactions. If multiple threads in a warp or multiple warps in a block have temporal and spatial locality then it can benefit performance to use a software maintained cache in shared memory or to try to optimize the use of the L1 cache or TEX cache. The optimal performance will be with using fully coalesced vector loads and stores.

Comment: @GregSmith - What do you mean by "inflight transactions" here? Thanks!

Comment: A memory transaction is in flight from the time the load store unit accepts the request to the time the data from the request is written back to the register file. SMs can have 10s-100s of in flight memory transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as burst mode. The fastest memory copy from global to shared memory is simply to do it with threads:

```
__global__ void mykernel(int *globaldata){

  __shared__ int localdata[256];
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
  if (threadIdx.x < 256)
    localdata[threadIdx.x] = globaldata[idx];
  __syncthreads();

  (... rest of kernel code)
}
```

If you launch the above kernel with at least 256 theads per block (and many blocks in your kernel), you'll get good memory bandwidth and utilization.

The CUDA C [best practices guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html) has more code examples about how to use [shared memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#shared-memory) to efficiently speed up various operations.